# will or going to here?

Tags: grammar, will-vs-going-to

I've come across this question in a textbook that does not have any answer key, unfortunately. Here is the question:

> **Complete the sentences with the correct form of will or going to:**
>
> My brother _____(not go) to university any more. He ___________(work) for a charity in Africa.

I think it's won't and going to as answers.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For the first, won't is suitable. Here we need *refusal*, which is a special usage of auxiliary verb **will**.

Consider the another example of this usage, the door won't open.

(1) My brother won't go to university any more. He is going to work
for a charity in Africa.

Instead of will, we use is going to, because he has a *plan* about
 a charity in Africa.

(2) Consider past tense :

My brother would not go to university any more. He was going to work
for a charity in Africa.

Here was going to means both plan and *not fulfilling*. Hence (1) is
more natural

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) it was really helpful !

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

for the second gap, it is obvious that "going" should be used because of "is".

for the former, because there is an intention to do, it seems "going" is more suitable.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no "is" in the first gap I thought it was "going to" and it was a mistake I edited that sorry again and thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Englishvibes then it seems that the "will" is suit for the latter gap.